# How can i execute a function of the child component sending a data?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3

i want to execute my function depends of the type, this function is in the child component,
childComponent:

```
methods: {
      searchButton (type)  {
        console.log(type)
        if(type==='1'){}
        if(type==='2'){}
        if(type==='3'){}
      },
    },
```

i would like to this component like this

```
<Child @emit="seachButton('1')"
```

its possible?

**Edit1: why the follow example does not work?**

i am sending from the parent
Parent.vue

```
<Child  @onClick="onClick1"/>
<Child  @onClick="onClick2"/>
<script>
  import Child from './Child.vue'
  export default {
    name: 'Tabs',
    props: {},
    components: {
      Child,
    },
    methods: {
      onClick1() {
        console.log('onClick1')
      },
      onClick2() {
        console.log('onClick2')
      },
```

and on my child component:

```
<template>
   <el-button @click="onClick" type="primary">{{ buttonText }}</el-button></template>

<script>
  export default {
    name: 'Child',
    props: {
      
    },
    methods: {
      onClick ()  {
        this.$emit('click')
      },
    },
  }
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just do want you want to do inside of your `child.vue` `methods` and use `emit` there too.

*First:* Do something in your `if-statement` and `emit` the value to your parent.vue:

```
methods: {
  searchButton (type)  {
    console.log(type)
    if(type==='1'){
      //just a e.g.
      this.value = type;
      this.$emit('myValue', this.value);
    }
    if(type==='2'){}
    if(type==='3'){}
   },
 },
```

*Second:* Define the `emitted` in your `parent.vue`

```
<Child @myValue="myValue"/>
```

*Third:* Reference second step and set a new variable in your `parent.vue` `methods` like this:

```
methods: {
  newValue(val) {                //val = your emitted value
    this.valueFromChild = val    //define your val in your parent.vue
  }
}
```

Hopefully this helps you out!

**Just for additional info:**

`EMIT` is to pass data from your child to your parent and will be declared like my e.g in step 2 (@example="example)

`PROPS` is to pass data from parent to child, these will declared in the `component-tag` like :example="example"

**UPDATE TO NEW EDIT**:

In your child.vue (!) `template` you have to define a `click-event` first when you want to do it after clicking on a button like in my code. Than go to your `methods` and define a `function` for each and `emit` this with a `name` and a `value` !

```
<template>
   <el-button type="primary" @click="triggerClick1()">{{ buttonText }}</el-button>
   <el-button type="primary" @click="triggerClick2()">{{ buttonText }}</el-button>
</template>
   

<script>
  export default {
    name: 'Child',
    methods: {
      triggerClick1() {
        this.$emit('onClick1', "First button was triggerd") 
      }
      triggerClick2() {
        this.$emit('onClick2', "Second button was triggerd")
      }
    },
  }
</script>
```

In you parent.vue (!) you have to declare but where you add your `component` than you go to your methods as well like in my code and declare your variable, than you can use it in your parent! Like this

```
<template>
  <Child  @onClick1="onClick1" @onClick1="onClick2"/>
</template>

<script>
  import Child from './Child.vue'
  export default {
    name: 'Tabs',
    props: {},
    components: {
      Child,
    },
    
    methods: {
        onClick1(val) {
            this.valClick1 = val;
        },
        
        onClick2(val) {
            this.valClick2 = val;
        }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: @BOBBY I edited my question using function on the side parent to execute any function on the child component but does not work

Comment: You dont need to use ```@click="onClick"``` in you child.vue just emit. ```<Child  @onClick="onClick1"/>``` here change it to ```<Child  @onClick="onClick"/>``` and delete the second one.

Comment: Do you want to pass something from parent to child or from child to parent?

Comment: @BOBBY i want to execute any function from parent to child, because child component have the button

Comment: updated my answer. Pls check

Answer (score 1):

An easier way would be using a `ref` like

```
<template>
  <Child @child-click="searchButton" ref="child_ref"/>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: 'Parent',
  methods: {
   searchButton (type)  {
        console.log(type)
        if(type==='1'){
           this.$refs.child_ref.handler1(); // can pass args if required
         }
        if(type==='2'){
         this.$refs.child_ref.handler1(); // can pass args if required
        }
      },
  }
}
</script>
```

and your child component be like

```
<template>
   <el-button @click="onClick" type="primary">{{ buttonText }}</el-button></template>

<script>
  export default {
    name: 'Child',
    methods: {
      onClick ()  {
        let someVal = 1 // can you any value that is used in if-else inside parent
        this.$emit('child-click', someVal) // changed the name becoz there is already a default handler called 'click`
      },
      handler1() {
      },
      handler2() {
      }
    },
  }
</script>
```

Comment: can you give +1 for my question please, i need reputation

Comment: Is this the answer you were expecting?

Comment: Lam the one who gave you that +1 :)

Comment: you can verify that by clicking the clock icon below the voting arrow in your question